# Gradle Clean Build Issues

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

> Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzcv found in modules classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:11.8.0) and classes.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:16.0.8)

I recently face this error from Gradle build

Android Manifest

```
 buildscript {
   repositories {
     maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
   }

 dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
 }
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

 repositories {
   maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
 }
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "tz.co.application.testExample"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 45
    versionName "1.0.45"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    multiDexEnabled = true

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}


dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8
}
buildToolsVersion = '28.0.3'

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'play-services-awareness'
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
 }

 dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

 implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:percent:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:palette-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

 implementation 'it.neokree:MaterialTabs:0.11'
 implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
 implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.0.3'
 implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.1'
 implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
 implementation 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2'
 implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.1.7'
 implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.1.0'
 implementation 'net.steamcrafted:materialiconlib:1.0.3'
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
 implementation 'agency.tango.android:material-intro-screen:0.0.5'
 implementation 'com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:1.4.0'
 implementation 'com.github.moondroid.coverflow:library:1.0'
 implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'
 implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.0.1'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
 implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
 implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
 implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
 implementation 'com.moos:Material-ProgressView:1.0.6'
 implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
 implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.9'
 implementation 'com.github.hannesa2:AndroidSlidingUpPanel:3.5.0'
 implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
 implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.7'
 implementation files('libs/httpclient-4.2.3.jar')
 implementation 'com.hover:android-sdk:1.4.3'
 implementation files('libs/skyepub.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
```

The gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/mobisystech/maven" }
}
dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'

}
}

 allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/mobisystech/maven" }
    maven { url "http://maven.usehover.com/releases" }
  }
 }

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What could be wrong??

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a command  run on terminal 
gradlew clean run
after that click invalid